# Es posible compilar para iOS para testing?

Tags: ios, phonegap

Necesito ayuda con esto, ya que necesito probar mi app en varios dispositivos antes de publicar. El problema es que tengo un Apple ID, y parece que ya no puedo tener un Certificado Provisorio. Hay alguna opción que me permita hacer eso ahora en Octubre 2016? Uso xCode 7 en iOS Yosemite y PhoneGap en Windows 7/8/8.1/10 pero siempre me tira el mismo error. "provisioning profile missing." Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: No tienes certificado y deseas probar si el?

Comment: Antes se podía, no se ahora, pero en sí me gustaría compilar solo para probar, como en Android.

Comment: Por que no puede obtener un certificado desde su Apple Id?

Answer (score 1):

Podrías realizar tus pruebas en otros dispositivos iOS por medio de TestFligth.
Necesitas preparar y subir a iTunes Connect y de ahi enviar a pruebas por medio de TestFligth. 
Puedes añadir a varias personas para prueben en sus dispositivos sin necesidad de conectar su dispositivo a tu mac.

https://developer.apple.com/testflight/

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente desde Xcode 7 en adelante, puedes firmar una aplicación para probar en un dispositivo físico con un perfil de pruebas por 7 días. Luego debes re-generar la firma en caso sea necesario.

Te dejo un link de referencia, pero el proceso es bastante automático: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30973799/ios-9-new-feature-free-provisioning-run-your-app-on-a-device-just-with-your-ap/32249026#32249026

Saludos.